# Make number Value opposite in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to know if it is possible to make a number the opposite to what it currently is using JavaScript. ie if a number is `400`. Is it possible to make it `-400`, similar if a number is `-400` is it possible to make it `400`?

Comment: `var num = 400; var num2 = -num;`?  This is basic JavaScript; basic programming.

Answer (score 9):

This is not jQuery!

Just multiply it by `-1`.

```
num = "400"
console.log(-num);
```

Comment: NO! You should totally use jQuery, it's awesome and do all things. I'm sure there's a basic arithmetic plugin available.

Comment: You can make it even smaller: `console.log(-num)` :-P

Comment: Plugin code: `$.inverseSign = function(n){ return -n; }` usage: `alert($.inverseSign(-4));`. Such a hard task needed a plugin, much better now. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pq5X/)

Comment: Remember, in math it is another way of writing `-1(num)` which is `-1 X num`.  This is *basic* math ;)

Answer (score 8):

Core JS,

```
function opposite(number) {
  return(-number);
}
```

As the shorter solution from http://www.codewars.com/

Answer (score 1):

In one Line..

```
 const opposite = number => -number;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const opposite(num) {
  return num * -1;
}
```

What I also realized was that if you just:

```
const opposite(num) {
  return -num;
}
```

The negative can be used to create a positive when returning the num because if it is a negative integer turning into a negative number the two negatives cancel each other out into a positive.

To shorten the code you can also use:

```
const opposite = num => -num;
```

All ways work. It's all in how fast you want the solution. The faster the better. The most simple way a code can be written the better.

I really liked @KRESH 's answer because it made me find out what Math.sign() was. The whole adventure of figuring out what his code did was fantastic. I wonder what it could be best used for. That's what's going to be fun figuring out next.

Comment: `const opposite(num) {` is invalid syntax...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function opposite(number) {
  let result;
  if (!isNaN(Math.sign(number))) {
    result = number * (-1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how this code works to make this answer more helpful.